# How do I scan riddler question marks?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've played through all of Arkham Asylum and I still don't remember how to do this - I see question marks all over the place in detective mode, but holding down "L2" doesn't seem to scan them no matter how I try to align it.  (I don't even get a "misaligned" message.)  How do you scan the question marks?

Comment: i cant use the scan on the detective mode either, it ssays you can actually use it but i can't. Ive just started the game so i suppose its a matter of playing more so they can actually teach you how to scan. Does anyone know anything else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> You need to be able to interrogate Riddler informants. The scan
>   feature unlocks after you question the first one, I think.

http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/6563-Can-t-Make-the-Riddler-s-Riddles-Work...

Comment: What a strange choice if this is the case. He brings almost all weapons and gadgets from the first game, but 'forgets' how to scan?

Comment: I found this to be correct.  FYI, you first find Riddler informants by finishing a sidequest - it happens in due time.

Comment: This was not true for me. I have not interrogated any Riddler Informants, but the option opened up for me once I reached the Steel Mill.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when i started the game! Once you enter one of the first areas in the story mode, the "scan" option opens up to you. You're prompted to scan two trophies locked in an elevator shaft so you can come back to them. Once you do that, you'll be able to scan whenever you'd like. Confusing, but that's how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Got it !   Just hold the same button down that you used to invoke detective mode, while aiming closely at a riddler trophy.

How could i forget. Landed here too, before figuring it out.
Playing on Onlive, in that case that means -> Hold the LB button to scan when you already are in Detective mode ;)

Which is also described in the cotrols pause menu

---

Also dont forget your DLC skin switching code ;)

To use the code, the following button combination must be pressed on the Main Menu screen after a save slot has been selected:

Left, Left, Down, Down, Left, Left, Right, Up, Up, Down

You'll hear thunder if done correctly

Answer (score 1):

I just tap the lb trigger. Some are hard to scan but if you go at them from a different angle it seems to work a tad better.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to line up a green question mark while in detective mode and scanning it. You need to hold down the detective mode button to scan it. LB on 360, and L2 on the PS3.

If you're not getting any type of message about nothing being found, or misaligned, then likely something else is going on.

Comment: I've found the green question marks, I line them up in detective mode, and hold L2.  Nothing happens - no scanning noise, motion, or anything.  And I've played the first game, so I know what's supposed to happen - it's supposed to tell me it's misaligned, or reveal that I hit the mark.

Comment: Are you sure that it's L2 then? I haven't played the PS3 version. Does a single click on L2 open detective mode like it used to? Something isn't right if it's not doing anything, so it's either the control scheme is different, it was changed or something else.

Comment: Can you try it on the first Riddler Locations listed here: http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/arkham-city-cheats/1097003/batman_arkham_city_riddler_trophies_collectables_and_challenges_locations_guide.html

Comment: L2 is definitely the PS3 detective mode.  I can try the first thing on that FAQ when I'm not working.

Comment: Work? You didn't take the day off to play? :)